# How to use the line-off function of HTML5 in Android？

Tags: android

The page can realize Cache when load html5 page in webview of Android. How to submit in the case of offline, and synchronous server when it online. I know HTML5 can achieve the function, but I do not know the details. How do I achieve it? Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When page was submitted,js call java code,determine whether the network connection normal.

If there is no network,then record the information in Java code,judge if the network is normal when a program restarts or timing.

If there is a network connection,then there have httpclient in java code,in java call page js code to submit.

Comment: your answer is good. could you change the punctuation? so many comma.